# Android - second onActivityResult not being called

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult

I have 3 classes from `FragmentActivity` called A - B - C...

`A` extends `Fragment` and calls to `B` using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT);
```

`B`extends `FragmentActivity` and calls to `C` using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT);
```

The problem is, whe return from `C`, using:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Instead to return to `onActivityResult` of `B`, it returns to `onActivityResult` of `A`.

How can I return step by step, coming in order through each `onActivityResult`?

Thanks in advance.